# Laravel 5.x Database Triggers and possible best practices

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, triggers, laravel-migrations

This post is to sort-of inform and ask a question.
Hello all,
    I'm developing a large system that puts triggers to good use. We're currently running the server-side on Laravel 5.2 with php 7 using phpmyadmin. Within Laravel there isn't really much solid documentation on how to use a trigger through migrations and from what I've discovered you mostly have to do it "raw".

Below is a simple example, that I know of, on how to write a trigger in a migration:

```
class CreateAccountTriggerTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function up() 
     {   
         DB::unprepared('
             CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger_name` AFTER INSERT ON `table_the_change_happened`
             FOR EACH ROW 

             BEGIN

             INSERT INTO `this_table`
                  (field1,field2,field3)
             VALUES
                  ('value1','value2','value3')

             END
         ');
     }

     /**
      * Reverse the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function down() {
          DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `my_trigger_name`');
     }
 }
```

**The Question:**
Does anyone know of a clean way to use variables within laravel's query builder?

The method DB::unprepared() does not allow you to attach bound items to it. Trying it in Eloquent is near impossible as there is no solid documentation that I've found for this issue. If anyone can elaborate on this I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance

**Update**
Per request here would be an example of what I mean by using a variable within laravel's query builder:

```
          $stuff = bcrypt($random_numbers);
          DB::unprepared('
             CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger_name` AFTER INSERT ON `table_the_change_happened`
             FOR EACH ROW 

             BEGIN

             INSERT INTO `this_table`
                  (field1,field2,field3)
             VALUES
                  ('value1','value2','value3',"$stuff")

             END
         ');
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "use variables within laravel's query builder"?

Comment: @patricus Sure thing! please see updated edits

Comment: This is one of the applications that Laravel's `Model Events` has. There's no need for a trigger to do this when you can just attach a model to `table_the_change_happened` and then in the `public function boot(){ parent::boot(); });` you can just add your logic to do the insert after the `parent::boot()`

Comment: Would that really be efficient when in terms of process, if you had over 50-80 different inserts to make across multiple tables? Understandable the image painted in my question was a simple use case however, in a real application using triggers for say (account setup) is more efficient. 
From what I understand, handling a process like that is generally seen as good practice to use triggers for large initial record setups. Even though that's an entirely different discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, I think you're looking for the `statement()` method, instead of the `unprepared()` method. The `statement()` method takes a query and an array of parameter bindings for that query.

Example below. The `?` in the values list is the query parameter. The value to bind to that parameter is added to an array passed in the second parameter to the `statement()` method.

```
$stuff = bcrypt($random_numbers);
DB::statement('
        CREATE TRIGGER `my_trigger_name` AFTER INSERT ON `table_the_change_happened`
        FOR EACH ROW 

        BEGIN

        INSERT INTO `this_table`
            (field1,field2,field3)
        VALUES
            ('value1','value2','value3',?)

        END
    ', [$stuff]);
```

Comment: I feel like it's close but the statement method prevents the trigger from being created entirely. I think it's because it needs to be acted on at some point.

Comment: I gave you a +1 because it got me going in the right direction. I thank you for helping head in the right direction! Below is my answer.