# Creating a new column in Laravel Schema builder, using the value of existing column by default

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a table, which contains an "email_address" field and an "activation hash" field.
The default value of "activation hash" field should be

```
sha1(microtime().email_address))
```

Is it possible to set this up using laravel migrations and how can I do this?

Surely, i should say, that i'm using postgres as DB engine

Comment: Since microtime is a PHP function, no. But you can use a Model Event for it: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events

Comment: Maybe you can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177303/laravel-5-x-database-triggers-and-possible-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

Most database engines are limited as to what values can be set as a default to columns. Depending on your database engine, you might be able to do it via an event/trigger but it's easier and arguably better to solve this at an application level with [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events).

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do something like this, I split the code in 2 pieces:

1. Create the column (using Schema Builder)
2. Set the value (over PHP, loading all models and updating one by one in a foreach)

***Note:*** Both steps can be done at migration file.

You can't do it entirely at MySQL (if you are using MySQL) query since it doesn't have a `microtime()` function.

But I found this UDF implementation for `microtime()` on MySql:

https://github.com/JohannesMP/MySQL-udf-microtime

If you are not updating a huge dataset, I would stick with the first solution. But if you are updating a huge dataset, so the MySQL implementation will be faster.

Comment: I'm using Postgres.