# Laravel 5.3 Writing a DB routine/subroutine in a migration file?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

In a previous question, I asked about how to write a trigger and gave a decent example of **one** way to write it in a laravel 5.X migration file. (note: hard/raw coded)

**Referenced Question:**

https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/39177303/laravel5-x-database-triggers-and-possible-best-practices

However, as the title states, does anyone know how to write a database routine/subroutine in a laravel migration file??

Or

Does anyone know of a clean way to implement using laravel's methods to create a migration file that will make subroutines or routines within a database?